# Open graph properties are specified but not supported

Tags: html, wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've been trying to set up the og properties of several articles but I'm facing an issue and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. I set up my properties using Yoast SEO, but when I'm trying to share the post on Facebook, the data provided is not correct.

Here's the error that I'm getting:

*The following properties are specified on the webpage but NOT supported for the specified 'og:type': article:publisher, article:author, article:section, article:published_time, article:modified_time, fb:appid*

```
 <meta name="google-site-verification" 
content="6bN5lpZ988fwDMWpXPO_2hWdYcXBlwyhJPOqNsbzwNo" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="Over the years, Romanian wine has 
attracted countless European business people and wine enthusiasts, mainly 
due to the affordable prices compared to countries such as Italy, France, or 
Germany. Discover the best wine regions and grape varieties in Romania." />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Discover the wines of Romania" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Explore Romania's best wine regions 
    and discover the grape varieties of Romania." />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://rolandia.eu/romanian-wine/" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Rolandia" />
    <meta property="article:publisher" 
    content="https://www.facebook.com/Rolandia.travel/" />
    <meta property="article:author" 
    content="https://www.facebook.com/cretu.bogdan.13" />
    <meta property="article:section" content="Discover Romania" />
    <meta property="article:published_time" content="2018-01-08T13:57:26+00:00" />
    <meta property="article:modified_time" content="2018-01-22T08:18:35+00:00" />
    <meta property="og:updated_time" content="2018-01-22T08:18:35+00:00" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="457855247901149" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://rolandia.eu/wp-    content/uploads/2018/01/open-graph-test.jpg" />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="Over the years, Romanian wine has attracted countless European business people and wine enthusiasts, mainly due to the affordable prices compared to countries such as Italy, France, or Germany." />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Discover the wines of Romania" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="http://rolandia.eu/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/twitter-cards-test.jpg" />
    <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.9.2" />
    <meta name="generator" content="WooCommerce 3.2.6" />
    <meta name="generator" content="WPML ver:3.9.1 stt:1,4,3;" />
    <meta property="fb:appid" content="1394793937256662" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Romanian wine" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://rolandia.eu/romanian-wine/" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Over the years, Romanian wine has attracted countless European business people and wine enthusiasts, mainly due to ..." />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://rolandia.eu/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/romanian-wine-300x200.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="384" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="250" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Rolandia" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Powered by Visual Composer - drag and drop page builder for WordPress." />
    <meta name="generator" content="Powered by Slider Revolution 5.4.5.1 - responsive, Mobile-Friendly Slider Plugin for WordPress with comfortable drag and drop interface." />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://rolandia.eu/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/cropped-Rolandia-favicon-270x270.png" />
URLs
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `og:type` is specified twice as `website` and as `article`. So you'll need to double check if multiple plugins or your theme is already adding this.

As a solution the most straightforward way would be to disable the one which is adding the wrong `og:type`. 
If that isn't an option you could always write an action in which you filter our the wrong values (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head).

In case you run into more trouble, you can always debug a page's og-tags using Facebook's debugger tool; https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I used the debugger to debug the page mentioned in your meta tags, and indeed Facebook sees the page as a `og:type` `website` making the error valid as these properties are for the ignored `og:type` `article`